# How to Print the particular contents in the entire document using DHTML

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dhtml, ihtmldocument2

In these example, I want to print the contents in the ID **tab_form_1**.While trying these 
sample to print the **tab_form_1** contents,lpOleCommandTarget become NULL while query interface using CComptr .

How to solve this issue?

**SAMMPLE**

```
    IHTMLDocument2 *pDoc;
GetDHtmlDocument(&pDoc);


CComPtr<IHTMLElement2> spControl;       
if(GetElementInterface(_T("tab_form_1") ,&spControl) != S_OK)
    return; 

//ole command target
LPOLECOMMANDTARGET lpOleCommandTarget = NULL;
spControl->QueryInterface(IID_IOleCommandTarget,(void**)&lpOleCommandTarget);ASSERT(lpOleCommandTarget);
//lpDispatch->Release();

if(lpOleCommandTarget == NULL) return;

//prepare header
CString header   = _T("Project Path: &w");

VARIANT     header_variant;
VariantInit(&header_variant);
V_VT(&header_variant)   = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&header_variant) = CString(header).AllocSysString();

//prepare footer
CString footer   = _T("&d &t&b Page&p of &P");

VARIANT     footer_variant;
VariantInit(&footer_variant);
V_VT(&footer_variant)   = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&footer_variant) = CString(footer).AllocSysString();

//prepare header footer safe arrray
SAFEARRAYBOUND  parameter_array_bound[1];
SAFEARRAY       *parameter_array = NULL;

parameter_array_bound[0].cElements = 2;
parameter_array_bound[0].lLbound   = 0;

parameter_array = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT,1,parameter_array_bound);

//HRESULT hr;
long index;

index = 0;
HRESULT hr    = SafeArrayPutElement(parameter_array,&index,&header_variant);

index = 1;
hr    = SafeArrayPutElement(parameter_array,&index,&footer_variant);

VARIANT parameter;
VariantInit(&parameter);
V_VT(&parameter)    = VT_ARRAY | VT_BYREF;
V_ARRAY(&parameter) = parameter_array;

// print contents of web browser control
lpOleCommandTarget->Exec(NULL, OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, &parameter,NULL);

//clear all variants
VariantClear(&header_variant);
VariantClear(&footer_variant);
if (parameter_array != NULL) {
    SafeArrayDestroy(parameter_array);
}

lpOleCommandTarget->Release();
```

Comment: @karthik:If I use pDoc to query the interface then it will print the entire html document.My task is to print the contents in the particular ID in that document to be printed.

Comment: @karthik:The Problem happens in this place:                      //ole command target
LPOLECOMMANDTARGET lpOleCommandTarget = NULL;
spControl->QueryInterface(IID_IOleCommandTarget,(void**)&lpOleCommandTarget);ASSERT(lpOleCommandTarget);

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample.This will eradicate your problem.This code will print the particular contents into the newly created document.

```
    // create DHtmlDocument for Newly Created Dialog
HRESULT hDispatch = printdlg->m_pBrowserApp->get_Document((IDispatch**)&pDisp);
if(hDispatch != S_OK) return;
HRESULT hResult = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&pNewDoc);
if(hResult != S_OK) return;

//GetDHtmlDocument for new document
GetDHtmlDocument(&pDoc);

BSTR strSummaryText = GetElementHtml(L"tab_form_1");

// Creates a new one-dimensional array
SAFEARRAY *psaStrings = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1);
if (psaStrings == NULL) {

    return;
}

VARIANT *param;
HRESULT hresult = SafeArrayAccessData(psaStrings, (LPVOID*)&param);
param->vt = VT_BSTR;
param->bstrVal = strSummaryText;

hresult = SafeArrayUnaccessData(psaStrings);
//it will write the div part of tab_form_1 into new document to pass the summary contents alone to the printer
hresult = pNewDoc->write(psaStrings);


// SafeArrayDestroy calls SysFreeString for each strtemp
if (psaStrings != NULL) {
    SafeArrayDestroy(psaStrings);
}
```